# How exactly does PHP remember session data?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Sorry for the open ended question, but please let me explain my situation. I have a website with a login system that keeps track of its logged in user via a session variable. When I first set it up, it was resetting on each browser restart. After looking in my php config, I saw that there was an option to set the cookie time in seconds. I set it for 1 week, rechecked, and sure enough, the cookie now said it expired in 1 week. However, it still resets me after a few hours, despite the cookie with the same session id still being there. It no longer resets with each browser restart, but will after about 2 or 3 hours of me coming back.

So with that being said, theres something I'm not understanding about how this works. Is the session data remembered by php on the server, and uses that cookie to restart it when the user connects? Is there some kind of garbage collection happening in the background I'm unaware of? How do I get it to remember the user for 1 whole week?

Thanks for any help